# What sync primitives can I use with clone(2) (C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

*What C++ synchronization primitives can I use when using Linux's clone(2) threads?*  I specifically cannot use pthreads because I'm building a shared library that replaces many of pthreads's function calls with different definitions, but I'm in need of a mutex of some sort.

EDIT: I might have spoke too soon, I looked at the pthread docs and they use a futex(2) to implement these primitives.  I'm assuming that is how I would do this, too?

Comment: Here is paper from Drepper about futexes http://www.cis.temple.edu/~ingargio/cis307/readings/futex.pdf and the Drepper is coauthor of glibc/NPTL. In the paper it is described how to use futex to build some sync primitives and the last "take" is really used in NPTL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `futex` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex

Here are simple mutex and cond var based on futex http://locklessinc.com/articles/mutex_cv_futex/

Comment: The man pages keep referring to `processes` -- does this apply to `threads`, too?

Comment: futexes are universal (both processes and threads). NPTL (the pthreads library of glibc >= 2.3) uses futex internally to implement almost everything: mutexes, barrier, condvars...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your requirements are for your synchronization tool you can also use atomic operations. E.g gcc's `__sync_lock_test_and_set` can be easily used for a spinlock. Such userspace locks that avoid system calls can in many cases be more efficient than kernel based solutions.

*Edit:* This is the case if you have just a few instructions to protect. Then the probability that a thread that has taken the spinlock is interrupted while holding the lock is very small.  *If* this happens, the waiting time would then be some scheduling cycles, something that on modern systems should only be a no-go for real-time systems. For the average waiting time this should be negligible.

Comment: But not every type of syncronization is easy to implement or effective when only atomic ops are used. Sometimes OS assist is needed and `futex` is good complement for atomic ops (actually NPTL uses both atomic and futex AND typical bare futex usage combines it with atomics too)

Comment: @osgx, sure. I only wanted to go against the idea that you necessarily need assistance from the OS kernel through system calls to implement mutual exclusion. If you just have some instructions to protect, a spinlock is the way to go.

Comment: Only when you have good scheduler (or no scheduler) and only N threads on M CPUs and N<=M; you can use spinlocks safely. If N>M, or 2 threads can be planned on the same CPU, spinlocks will concurent with each other and sync primitive will be as slow as scheduler tick (1ms). So the sync operation writer need assistance from OS in some rare cases to get effective and universal implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The proper implementation of a futex-based Mutex is described in Ulrich Drepper's paper "Futexes are tricky". The link osgx gave in his comment is outdated. The current version is here:

http://people.redhat.com/drepper/futex.pdf

It includes not only the code but also a very detailed explanation of why it is correct. The code from the paper:

```
class mutex
{
 public:
 mutex () : val (0) { }
 void lock () {
   int c;
   if ((c = cmpxchg (val, 0, 1)) != 0)
     do {
       if (c == 2 || cmpxchg (val, 1, 2) != 0)
         futex_wait (&val, 2);
     } while ((c = cmpxchg (val, 0, 2)) != 0);
 }
 void unlock () {
   if (atomic_dec (val) != 1) {
     val = 0;
     futex_wake (&val, 1);
   }
 }
 private:
   int val;
};
```

cmpxchg() and atomic_dec() can be implemented via __sync_val_compare_and_swap() and __sync_fetch_and_add() respectively, which are not standard C but supported by GCC and AFAIK by CLANG, too.

Note, that futex() is Linux-specific. FreeBSD has an emulation AFAIK but I don't know if you can access it natively. If you want to target other platforms than Linux, you cannot use futex(). But since you're using clone() which is Linux-specific, you probably don't care.

About your idea of writing a pthreads-replacement in general:

Forget it.

I went down that route myself because I wanted to have some behaviour offered by clone() but not by pthread_create(). After a while I gave up. glibc is built on the assumption that you are using pthreads. Even (or especially) if you don't link with -lpthread, glibc includes pthread-specific behaviour. The thing that made me give up on clone() was errno. In a multithreaded application you have to provide a thread-local errno unless you want to synchronize each and every libc call with a global mutex. You do that by implementing __errno_location(). Unfortunately glibc has its own __errno_location hardcoded in some places and will not use your replacement.

In other words: If you want to use your own threading library, you cannot use glibc, at least not without reading the source code to each and every function you use and being prepared to replace it if necessary. And if you're thinking of using uClibc instead, I'll have to disappoint you. They copied parts of their implementation from glibc and at least older versions have the above __errno_location issue.

My solution was to give up fighting pthreads. I now use pthread_create() to create my threads (with a nice C++ wrapper, of course). While I haven't tried it yet, the unshare(2) system call should allow me to change those aspects of the thread that I would have liked to set via clone() which pthread_create() doesn't support. If that doesn't work, I will take the glibc source for pthread_create() and hack my options into its call to clone(), keeping the rest identical so that I don't break compatibility.

As for synchronization primitives: Using pthread_create() does NOT force you to use pthread_mutex and company. Because I'm writing a VM where every object has a mutex assigned I don't want the space overhead of pthread_mutex_t. Instead I'm using Drepper's Mutex class from the paper above. You can freely mix and match pthread's primitives and your own. Wherever possible you should use the pthread versions because they are well tested. But for special cases (such as the extremely lightweight mutex) it's okay to create your own futex-based primitives.